# Windows VMWare Server 2.0 Connect CDROM from command-line

Tags: vmware-server

How do I connect/disconnect a CDROM drive from a virtual machine from the command-line?  I don't see anything in the VIX reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the vmware-vim-cmd line tool. For example, if your VM is vmid 112, and the CDROM deviceKey is 3002, the command will be:

```
vmware-vim-cmd vmsvc/device.connection 112 3002 true
```

You can discover the vmid with the command:

```
vmware-vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
```

Then you can find the device ID with the command:

```
vmware-vim-cmd vmsvc/device.getdevices <vmid>
```

Comment: On my VMWare Server 2.0 installation on a Windows Server 2003 machine, I can't find vmware-vim-cmd.  Which directory is it installed in by default?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't have a Windows machine with Server installed on it to look around. Maybe something in `c:\program Files\VMware`? You could also look for vimsh.exe or any vmware-*.exe to find possible locations.

Comment: I searched the entire hard drive and didn't find vmware-vim-cmd.  I don't think it comes with the Windows version of VMWare Server.